# Como puedo enviar un objeto JSON a un PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Quiero mandar una string JSON de Javascript a PHP, y despues en PHP hacer un json_decode, pero me falla una cosa.

```
function request(data)
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            var response = xhttp.responseText;
            console.log(response);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "points.php", true);
    xhttp.send(data);
}
```

En donde sale xhttp.send le paso un JSON.stringify.

```
var data = {user: user, points:points};
request(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Mi problema es el siguiente, en PHP, que tengo que poner para poder recibir la variable data? Yo tengo lo siguiente:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST["data"], true);
```

Pero me sale error:

> Undefined index data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que enviaste mediante XMLHttpRequest es un `Request Payload`, que básicamente lo que hace es escribir en el cuerpo de la petición HTTP el payload enviado. Si miras en la consola de red de chrome o algún otro navegador, verás algo como esto:

[image]

que indica que no se enviaron los datos como  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` sino que como un `text/plain` o `text/json` .

Ahora, para leer estos datos en PHP basta con utilizar lo siguiente:

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($payload);
json_decode($payload);
var_dump($payload);
```

lo que retorna:

```
string(13) "{"a":1,"b":2}"

object(stdClass)#40 (2) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(1)
  ["b"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

saludos

Comment: Ok, muchas Gracias!

Comment: @marc recuerda marcar como solucionado si te ayudó realmente o indicar acá algún otro problema para ayudarte :)

Answer (score 2):

> Lo qué sucede es que el **Request Header** (*cabecera de la petición*) está cómo **text/plain** o **text/json** y no como **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** que es el formato que acepta las peticiones **query_string** y **json**.

### Paso 1: En JS - Agregar antes de onreadystatechange la **Request Header**.

`xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

### Paso 2: En JS - Te recomiendo tener un elemento padre en el JSON

`const jsonAEnviar = "json=" + JSON.stringify({user: user, points:points});`

### Paso 3: En PHP - Modificar el código por el siguiente

`$jsonRecibido = json_decode($_POST['json']);`

---

#### Te adjunto una chuletilla que me monté hace tiempo para el tema de los tratamientos de respuestas en PHP.

> Maneras de recibir los datos *JSON*, *query_string*, *text_plain*...

```
// No datos y Respuesta como 'PLAIN_TEXT'

echo 'algun_texto_plano';

// No datos y Respuesta como 'JSON'

echo json_encode(["clave"=>"valor"]);

// Datos como 'QUERY_STRING' y Respuesta como 'QUERY_STRING'

echo $_REQUEST['nombre'] . ' ' . $_REQUEST['edad'];

// Datos como 'QUERY_STRING' y Respuesta como 'JSON'

$json = ["nombre" => $_REQUEST['nombre'] , "edad" => $_REQUEST['edad']];
echo json_encode($json);

// Datos como 'JSON' y Respuesta como 'QUERY_STRING'

$json = json_decode($_REQUEST['json']);
echo $json->nombre . ' ' . $json->edad;

// Datos como 'JSON' y Respuesta como 'JSON'

$datos = json_decode($_REQUEST['json']);
$respuesta = ["nombre" => $datos->nombre , "edad" => $datos->edad];
echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

> Clase de utilidad para Ajax nativo:

```
class Ajax {

    // OBTENER INSTANCIA AJAX

    static getXHR() {
        return typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined'
            ? new XMLHttpRequest() // Navegadores modernos
            : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP'); // Navegadores obsoletos
    }

    // REALIZAR PETICIÓN GET

    static doGET(url, params = null, onFinish) {
        const xhr = Ajax.getXHR();
        xhr.open('GET', url + (params === null ? '' : '?'+params), true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                onFinish = onFinish(xhr.status, xhr.responseText, xhr);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    };

    // REALIZAR PETICIÓN POST

    static doPOST(url, params, onFinish) {
        const xhr = Ajax.getXHR();
        xhr.open('POST', url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                onFinish = onFinish(xhr.status, xhr.responseText, xhr);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(params);
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

no necesitas hacer nada raro mira con tu función.

```
function request(data)
{
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            var response = xhttp.responseText;
            console.log(response);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "points.php", true);
    xhttp.send(data);
}
```

En PHP solo necesitas usar la variable post como la usas normalmente

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$points = $_POST['points'];
```